# Create a Directory under Library/Caches in PhoneGap iOS Application

Tags: mobile, directory, filesystems, cordova

I can put my data in directory of Documents folder of App, but it has been rejected from Apple for reason of not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

Trying to figure out how to create a directory under Library/Cache in iOS on the file system using PhoneGap.

I want to create a directory for my PhoneGap application, so I can store images and JSON data user synced from server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I use `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);`, it save my file to Documents folder under my App, so I got Apple rejected. The reason is the system backup all data under Documents folder to iCould after iOS6, so Apple does not allow big data like images or JSON file which could sync from your server again to keep in this folder.

So I use `LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY` instead. It does not save the data to Library/Cache, but it save data to temp folder of App, which does not been auto backup to iCloud and not auto deleted either. Finally, my application has been passed Apple review.

Comment: I wish PhoneGap provided a way to directly store under the Library/Caches directory as well. Maybe a constant for CACHE as well just like LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY

Comment: Yes, hope they add that for next couple of version.

Comment: @Wen I am having the same issue. I managed to download and display some images on Android, but was unsuccessful on iOS. So there is no option to download images to a folder that will get removed with the app? In Android that is file:///storage/sdcard0/my.app.id/cache/ for me but in iOS I can't get other path than file:///var/mobile/Applications/app.id/Documents/ when requesting file system. Any luck after using TEMPORARY?

Comment: @trainoasis I use window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, writeTextFile, fail); working for both Android and iOS.

Comment: But this way you have to remove the files yourself? They won't get deleted when you remove the app right? I reckon you didn't find an option to save them this way?

Comment: @trainoasis No, you don't need delete it by yourself. It will be removed when app been deleted.

Comment: @Wen but files can be removed sometimes even if you don't want them to if they are in tmp right?

Comment: @trainoasis Yes, it could be removed. Local storage might be a good solution for you.

Comment: @Wen can't store images there right? except maybe as base64 :) A different approach works for me now, thanks

Comment: working just fine! i have had a really bad time with this dummy issue and this fixed the problem once you set to use TEMPORARY just have to ref with your static file path "var fileURLStatic = "cdvfile://localhost/temporary";